# "Непонятки" с пустой строкой из документации java

Tags: java, cleancode

> 8.1 Blank Lines
>
> One blank line should always be used in the following circumstances:
>
> 1) Between methods
>
> 2)Between the local variables in a method and its first statement
>
> 3)Before a block (see section 5.1.1) or single-line (see section 5.1.2) comment
>
> 4)Between logical sections inside a method to improve readability

Под blank line понимается именно это:

```
int x;
//Новая строка(blank line)
int y;
```

Как тогда это понимать: "Между локальными переменными в методе и их первыми определениями"(надеюсь, правильный перевод)?

Приведу одно правило из документации:

> Если начальное значение не зависит от вычислений, выполняемых первыми, необходимо инициализировать локальные переменные там, где они объявлены.

Значит теперь мы точно знаем, что это принимает следующий вид:

```
int x; // в начале метода 
//код 
x = r/2*9; //где r вычисляется в коде( /2*9 - для примера)
```

Тогда причем тут пустая строка? Между блоком кода и первой инициализацией ее вставлять?

Comment: Пустая строка - это пустая строка (на которой ничего нет), а не перенос строки.

Comment: @insolor То есть второй вариант. Тогда как быть с "первым определением"?

Comment: Предполагается, видимо, что между объявлением и первым определением ничего нет (нет никаких вычислений). Т.е.  без пустой строки - это две строки одна за другой.

Comment: @insolor это не так, так как до этого есть правило "Если начальное значение не зависит от вычислений, выполняемых первыми, необходимо инициализировать локальные переменные там, где они объявлены."(да, я разбираю и записываю это, чтобы потом выучить).

Comment: Вследствие того, что теперь я точно знаю, что это второй вариант, я сейчас подредактирую вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, имеется в виду "между объявлением локальных переменных метода и его (метода) первыми действиями". Например:

```
{
    int counter=0;
    int someInt;

    //code
}
```

Comment: Хм, а ларчик просто открывался. Спасибо!